# Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Int'

Tags: swift, tableview

The error I get when I want to find the sum of the data in coredata.
The coredata "kisi.oyuncu1_puan" variable is defined as a string. It must be Int for addition. The conversion process did not happen.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "puanHucre", for: indexPath) as! PuanTableViewCell
    
    let kisi = oyuncuAd[indexPath.row]
    
    
    cell.kacinciElLabel.text = oyunElSayisi[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.oyuncu1PuanLabel.text = kisi.oyuncu1_puan
    cell.oyuncu2Puan.text = kisi.oyuncu2_puan
    cell.oyuncu3Puan.text = kisi.oyuncu3_puan
    cell.oyuncu4Puan.text = kisi.oyuncu4_puan
    
   
    var toplam = 0
   
    for x in [kisi.oyuncu1_puan] {
         
        toplam = toplam + x `***Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'Int'***`
       print(toplam)
        
     }
    
    return cell
    
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esDCO.png)

Comment: Conversion doesn't "happen" in Swift. It is up to you to unwrap / coerce as needed.

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image

Answer (score 1):

If `cell.oyuncu1PuanLabel.text = kisi.oyuncu1_puan` compiles then the for loop makes no sense because there is only one **string**.

If so replace the for loop with

```
if let kisi.oyuncu1_puan = kisi.oyuncu1_puan, 
   let intValue = Int(kisi.oyuncu1_puan) {
     toplam += intValue
     print(toplam) 
}
```

It safely unwraps the optional and converts - if possible - the String to Int.

And please, this is Swift. Snake_case variable names are *unswifty*.

Comment: I'm getting an error in the code you shared. It wants me to change it to if case not if let. When I correct the lines, the numbers are written one under the other. I want it to collect.

Comment: It's unclear what you are going to accomplish. Be aware that `cellForRowAt` is called **once per row** and `toplam` is a local variable which is set to zero in each call of `cellForRowAt`

Comment: I did what you said, but instead of adding the numbers, it just writes them one after the other.

Comment: I misspelled array in loop part. The problem comes from that. no problem thanks everyone.